# How to Stop Animation of the Arrow of the SpeedView in Android Using Speedometer library

Tags: java, android

I tried to stop the Animation of arrow in the speedview through the java code but is not working.

```
<com.github.anastr.speedviewlib.SpeedView
     android:id="@+id/performance_speedometer"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     app:sv_endDegree="@integer/degree360"
     app:sv_startDegree="@integer/degree180"
     app:sv_unit="" />
```

Java

```
    binding.performanceSpeedometer.setLowSpeedPercent(25);
    binding.performanceSpeedometer.setLowSpeedColor(Color.RED);
    binding.performanceSpeedometer.setMediumSpeedPercent(50);
    binding.performanceSpeedometer.setMediumSpeedColor(Color.YELLOW);
    binding.performanceSpeedometer.setHighSpeedColor(Color.GREEN);
    binding.performanceSpeedometer.setTextSize(0);
    binding.performanceSpeedometer.setSpeedTextSize(0);
    binding.performanceSpeedometer.speedTo(12f);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

no need to write any code in java just add this line to xml

```
 app:sv_withTremble="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need change programmatically in code:

```
speedometer.setWithTremble(false);
```